# Lambda-expression as an unevaluated sub-expressions of a constant expression

Tags: c++, c++11, constexpr

Excuse me for the long post, but I can't get this program to work unless I specify `-fpermissive` to gcc and not at all under clang. Can you please help fix this example?

```
namespace detail
{

template<typename T>
constexpr auto address(T&& t) ->
  typename ::std::remove_reference<T>::type*
{
  return &t;
}

template <typename FP, FP fp, class C, typename ...A>
struct S
{
  static constexpr auto* l = false ? address(
    [](C* const object) noexcept
    {
      return [object](A&& ...args) {
        return (object->*fp)(::std::forward<A>(args)...); 
      };
    }) :
    nullptr
  ;
};

template <typename FP, FP fp, typename R, class C, typename ...A>
auto make_member_delegate(C* const object, R (C::* const)(A...)) ->
  decltype((*S<FP, fp, C, A...>::l)(object))
{
  return (*S<FP, fp, C, A...>::l)(object);
}

}

template <typename FP, FP fp, class C>
auto make_member_delegate(C* const object) ->
  decltype(detail::make_member_delegate<FP, fp>(object, fp))
{
  return detail::make_member_delegate<FP, fp>(object, fp);
}

struct A
{
  void hello()
  {
    ::std::cout << "it worked" << ::std::endl;
  }
};

int main()
{
  A a;

  auto d(make_member_delegate<decltype(&A::hello), &A::hello>(&a));

  d();

  return 0;
}
```

Errors are (first gcc, then clang++):

gcc-4.9.0:

```
t.cpp:20:26: error: 'constexpr detail::S<void (A::*)(), &A::hello, A>::<lambda(A*)>* const detail::S<void (A::*)(), &A::hello, A>::l', declared using local type 'detail::S<void (A::*)(), &A::hello, A>::<lambda(A*)>', is used but never defined [-fpermissive]
   static constexpr auto* l = false ? address(
```

clang++-3.4.2:

```
t.cpp:21:5: error: a lambda expression may not appear inside of a constant expression
    [](C* const object) noexcept
    ^
t.cpp:33:14: note: in instantiation of template class 'detail::S<void (A::*)(), &A::hello, A>' requested here
  decltype((*S<FP, fp, C, A...>::l)(object))
             ^
t.cpp:32:6: note: while substituting deduced template arguments into function template 'make_member_delegate' [with FP = void
      (A::*)(), fp = &A::hello, R = void, C = A, A = <>]
auto make_member_delegate(C* const object, R (C::* const)(A...)) ->
     ^
t.cpp:41:6: note: while substituting deduced template arguments into function template 'make_member_delegate' [with FP = void
      (A::*)(), fp = &A::hello, C = A]
auto make_member_delegate(C* const object) ->
```

Strangely, the canonical PYTHY example compiles without issue under clang-3.4.2

Comment: clang is correct, you can't have a lambda in a constant expression. Is there any reason why you think this code *should* compile?

Comment: @Brian Look [here](http://pfultz2.github.io/Pythy/) and try to compile with clang and it will work.

Comment: @user1095108 What makes you think the article you referenced is correct?

Comment: @CaptainObvlious Because I can compile its code with clang without errors.

Comment: [Quick and dirty fix](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/a7b19bfb66454064)

Comment: @Brian both compilers are correct, standard doesn't distinguish between warning and error.

Comment: @dyp thanks, but I wanted to do it without a helper function object :) That is, the c++14 way, yet c++11 compatible, lambda returning lambda.

Comment: @user1095108 I don't think that's possible in a constant expression.

Comment: @dyp Well, gcc compiles with -fpermissive, I guess it's possible and don't forget PYTHY itself, which works with clang.

Comment: Ok, mind blown. It appears that *lambda-expressions* **may** appear as unevaluated sub-expressions of a constant expression, see [CWG DR 1607](http://www.open-std.org/JTC1/SC22/WG21/docs/cwg_defects.html#1607). And indeed, [this simple example works](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/fd3b144f40b7eafa) but when you turn that class into a class template, compilation fails. This smells like a bug. I'm not sure though if using this lambda pointer isn't technically UB.

Comment: @dyp I understand line #30 return {object}; of your http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/a7b19bfb66454064 constructs an initializer for the helper_fo instance to be returned. Do you know if a special name for this technique exists?

Comment: @Solkar Maybe it falls into the category of *uniform initialization* (using a braced-init-list in a return-statement or to construct a function parameter). In C++1y, we'll probably see it less often in favour of return type deduction.

Comment: @dyp: Yes, the PYTHY code formally invokes UB. The PYTHY author tries to explain it as "ok" because he doesn't access anything inside the lambda - UB is still UB though.

Comment: I [filed a bug report](http://llvm.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=20209) since the behaviour is still the same for clang++ trunk.

Comment: @dyp Thanks! File one for g++ too perhaps?

Comment: I'd wait a bit and see what the clang folks say. If it's illegal after all, there's no need to file one.

Answer (score -1):

Here's a fix for `gcc-4.9.0`, but the program still won't compile with `clang-3.4.2`:

```
template <typename FP, FP fp, typename R, class C, typename ...A>
auto make_delegate(C* const object, R (C::* const)(A...)) ->
  decltype((*decltype(S<FP, fp, C, A...>::l)(nullptr))(object))
{
  return (*decltype(S<FP, fp, C, A...>::l)(nullptr))(object);
}
```